# How to set up keyboard layout in GRUB2 Shell with sabayon

Tags: grub2, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, sabayon

I have an Italian keyboard and I want to set up the correct layout in GRUB shell.

I found many tutorials online that make use of `grub-kbdcomp` or `grub-mklayout`,
but those commands don't work on my distribution.

How can I set the proper layout?

Answer (score 1):

`grub-kbdcomp` is just a shell script that is a wrapper for the Debian `ckbcomp` utility and `grub-mklayout`. No Sabayon Linux Entropy package for ckbcomp exists, although there is a Gentoo Portage package which can be installed in Sabayon linux and used as shown below.

1. As there is no Entropy package for `ckbcomp`, install it via Portage.

1.1 Install Gentoo's Portage overlay manager.

```
    # equo install git
    # equo install layman
```

1.2 Synchronise the Gentoo Portage package ebuild tree.

```
    # emerge --sync # Do not update portage if told to do so.
```

1.3 Synchronise the Sabayon distribution's Gentoo Portage overlay package ebuild tree.

```
    # layman -S
```

1.4 Add the Sabayon distribution's Gentoo Portage overlay.

```
    # layman -a sabayon-distro
```

1.5 Synchronise the Sabayon distribution's Gentoo Portage overlay package ebuild tree.

```
    # layman -S
```

1.6 Install `sys-apps/ckbcomp` via Portage as there is no Entropy package.

```
    # emerge -1v ckbcomp # Ignore any Gentoo news items.
```

1.7 Tell Entropy what you did via Portage.

```
    # equo rescue spmsync
```

2. Create a new sub-directory to store the GRUB keyboard layout file.

   ```
   # mkdir /boot/grub/layouts
   ```
3. Convert the X11 keymap to the GRUB keymap. The X11 keymap `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/it` must exist for this to work.

   ```
   # ckbcomp it nodeadkeys | grub2-mklayout -o /boot/grub/layouts/it.gkb
   Unknown keyboard scan code 0x54
   Unknown keyboard scan code 0x65
   Unknown keyboard scan code 0x7f
   ```
4. Append '`GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT=at_keyboard`' in `/etc/default/grub`.

   ```
   # nano /etc/default/grub
   # tail -n 1 /etc/default/grub
   GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT=at_keyboard
   ```
5. Add `insmod` and `keymap` lines as shown below.

   ```
   # nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom
   # tail -n 2 /etc/grub.d/40_custom
   insmod keylayouts
   keymap $prefix/layouts/it.gkb
   ```
6. Check what locales are available.

   ```
   # locale --all-locales | grep -i it
   ```
7. Change/add locale (only) to `/etc/default/sabayon-grub` as shown below. Leave other entries, if any, in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` as they are.

   ```
   # nano /etc/default/sabayon-grub
   # grep locale /etc/default/sabayon-grub 
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="locale=it_IT dolvm rd.lvm.lv=sabayon_sabayon/swap rd.lvm.lv=sabayon_sabayon/root resume=/dev/mapper/sabayon_sabayon-swap splash vconsole.keymap=it rd.vconsole.keymap=it quiet"
   ```
8. Regenerate the `grub.cfg` file.

   ```
   # grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
   ```
9. Check that `grub.cfg` has been modified accordingly:

   ```
   # grep terminal_input /boot/grub/grub.cfg
   terminal_input at_keyboard
   # grep gkb /boot/grub/grub.cfg
   keymap $prefix/layouts/it.gkb
   # grep layouts /boot/grub/grub.cfg
   insmod keylayouts
   keymap $prefix/layouts/it.gkb
   ```
10. If the machine uses UEFI rather than PC BIOS, update the GRUB files in the EFI directory.

    ```
    # grub2-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi
    ```
11. Reboot to check if the `it` keymap has been loaded for the GRUB shell.

    ```
    # systemctl reboot
    ```